# Connection Time out in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have installed Node Js(v6.1.0) and MongoDB in my Ubuntu Server.

In package.json, I have the following code,

```
package.json:
{
"name":"restful",
"main":"server.js",
"dependencies":{
"express":"latest",
"mongoose":"latest",
"node-restful":"latest"
}
}
```

In server.js, I have the following code,

```
var express=require('express'),
    restful=require('node-restful'),
    mongoose=restful.mongoose;

 var app=express();

  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(bodyParser());
  var methodOverride = require('method-override')

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/restful');
 var ProductSchema=mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  sku:String,
  price:Number
 });
 var Products=restful.model('products',ProductSchema);
 Products.methods(['get','put','post','delete']);
 Products.register(app,'/api/products');

 app.listen(3000);
 console.log('Server is running at port 3000');
```

When I run the code node server.js in terminal, it says **"Server is running at port 3000"**. When I tried in browser say, 
**http://example.com:3000/api/products**,

it shows **"The site can't be reached.Connection timed out"**

But the above code is working fine in localhost. In server it is not working.

I have installed npm also.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your are you working on localhost so visit

http://localhost:3000/api/products or 127.0.0.1:3000/api/products if you working on some live server then enter correct domain address/ipaddress